# Prove the existence of the number $n$ that satisfies a property.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

### **Problem**

Prove that there is a $n \in$ $ \mathbb{N} $ such that the equation has at least 2022 solutions.

$x+y+\sqrt{xy}=n$ ,with  $x,y\in$ $ \mathbb{N}$

### **Attempt**

My first attempt was to fix $x$ to $0, 1, 2$ and try to simplify the problem a bit but it would not work.
I continued and wrote a c++ code in order to vizualize the expressions for a $n$ up to a large number, but it did not help me visualize any pattern.

I thought about considering the function $f(x,y) = x+y+\sqrt{xy}$. We want to find a positive integer $n$ such that $f(x,y) = n$ has at least 2022 solutions in positive integers $x$ and $y$.

Let $k$ be a positive integer. We claim that if we choose $n$ such that $n\geq k+2$ and $n^2-k\geq 4n$, then the equation $f(x,y) = n$ has at least $k+1$ solutions in positive integers $x$ and $y$.

And, here I am completely stuck! Any help or idea would be apprecieted!

Comment: If you set u=n  - x - y and v = xy, we can write the expression as v = u^2. So u=t and v=t^2 gives x+y = n-t and t^2 = xy. You can reduce this system to a question about whether or not you can find natural numbers t given a fixed such that the resulting parameterizations for x and y both yield natural numbers. This should help you visualize the problem on your computer if you need to think about it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you focus on just finding an $n$ with many solutions (obviously $2022$ in the problem statement is just a placeholder for 'how many you want'), this problem is easy if you go the other way around: Find parameterized solutions $(x,y,n)$, then choose the parameters such that the same $n$ appears as often as you want.

Since $\sqrt{xy}$ needs to be an integer, given any $x$, choosing $y=x$ seems to be the most immediate choice to make that true. That means $n=x+x+\sqrt{x\times x}=3x$. This means $(x,x,3x)$ is a solution triple.

That means any $n$ divisible by $3$ has at least $(x,y)$ solution, namely $x=y=\frac{n}3$. But for a given $n$, this is only one solution.

But the method can be easily generalized by seeing that $y=k^2x$ for $k \in \mathbb N, k \ge 1$ also leads to a natural $\sqrt{xy}$ (the above is just $k=1$).

In that case, we get $n=x+k^2x+\sqrt{x\times k^2x} = x+k^2x+kx=(1+k+k^2)x.$

That means for each positive $x$ and $k \in \mathbb N$,

$$(x, k^2x,(1+k+k^2)x) \tag{1}$$
is a solution triple.

That means any $n$ divisible by $1+k+k^2$ has a solution of the form $(1)$. That means you 'only' need to find an $n$ that is divisible by $1+k+k^2$ for $2022$ different values of $k$, say $k=1,2,\ldots,2022$. It will be very large, but it certainly exists, let's call it $n_{2022}$.

For different $k$ the $x$ and $y$ values generated by $(1)$ are all different, because for example $x=\frac{n_{2022}}{1+k+k^2}$ and the denominator is a strictly increasing function of $k$ for positive $k$, so all the $x$ values are different.

Comment: best answer till now (+1)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Prove by induction on the (at least) number of solutions.
If you have an $n$ with at least $k$ solutions of the form $(x_i, y_i)$, then $an$ also has at least $k$ solutions of the form $(ax_i, ay_i)$.
So, for a specially selected $a$, if we can find another solution in which $x_i$ is not a multiple of $a$, then this gives us at least $k+1$ solutions.

> EG Take $ a = 1 + n  + n^2$, then $ x = n, y = n^3$ satisfies $ x + y + \sqrt{xy} = an$.
>  So $ (n, n^3, an)$ is our $k+1$st solution.

---

In fact, modifying that idea, if we have solutions $(x_i, y_i , n_i)$ with $\frac{x_i}{y_i}$ distinct, then we can combine them to get the distinct pairs $X_i = x_i \prod_{j\neq i}  n_j, Y_i = y_i \prod_{j\neq i} n_j$ which satisfy $X_i + Y_i + \sqrt{X_iY_i} = \prod n_i$.
EG You can pick any squares $x_i, y_i$, as long as they satisfy the distinct condition.

As an explicit construction, with $(x_i, y_i, n_i) = (1, i^2, 1+i+i^2)$, we get that $n = \prod_{j=1}^{2022} (1 + j + j^2)$ has the following 2022 solutions:

$$x_i = \frac{1}{ 1 + i + i^2} \prod (1+j+j^2), \quad y_i = \frac{i^2}{1+i+i^2} \prod ( 1 + j + j^2) .$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the induction? A proper solution please? Many thanks! @CalvinLin

Comment: @MogovanJonathan Can you show your work? If you're stuck, explain what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, my understanding of your hints is ambiguous. I would appreciate if you would like more hints, or a proper solution. Sorry! Thank you!

Comment: @MogovanJonathan I would appreciate if you put some effort, instead of just giving up after a few minutes. Give it a try, and be specific with what you're stuck pushing through. EG Do you understand the structure of the proof? Do you understand what is expected of the missing step? Why aren't you able to complete the missing step?

Comment: I will continue trying, I am not an IMO medalist though:) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is actually quite solvable exactly in terms of a rational parameterization. It just takes a bit of work to get there. Writing

$n - (x+y) = \sqrt{xy} $

$n^2 -2n(x+y) + x^2 +2xy + y^2 = xy $

$n^2 -2n(x+y) + x^2 +xy + y^2 = 0 $

So we have a quadratic function in terms of x and y. We rewrite this expression in the following convenient manner

$x^2 + 2( \frac{y}{2} -n )x + y^2 -2ny + n^2 =0 $

Completing the square in terms of $x$, that is adding and subtracting $ (\frac{y}{2} - n)^2$ to the left hand side, we can simply the equation in terms of

$(x+ \frac{y}{2} - n)^2 + \frac{3}{4}y^2 - ny =0 $

Setting $u = x+ \frac{y}{2} - n$, can find a nice expression

$u^2 + \frac{3}{4}y^2 - ny =0 $

So now we can find a convenient way to express this for the purpose of analyzing the equations

$\frac{ny}{ u^2 + \frac{3}{4} y^2 }{ny} = 1 $

The function

$ F(u, y ) = \frac{ u^2 + \frac{3}{4} y^2 }{ny}$

is homogenous of order 1, so it can be written in the form $ F = uf(\frac{y}{u}) $ for example. So it is reasonable to conclude that setting $ y = t u$, we can solve for $u$ in terms of the parameter $t$ in the given equation. Therefore,

$u^2 + \frac{3}{4} t^2 y^2 - nt u =0 $

$u[ (1 + \frac{3}{4} t^2 ) u - nt ] =0$

So either $u=0$, or

$u = \frac{4nt}{4 + 3 t^2} $; $ y = \frac{4nt^2}{4 + 3 t^2}$

You can now solve for $x$ in terms of $u$ and $y$ and to find a rational parameterization for $x$ and $y$ which you can simplify to a nice form and check that this is satisfies the initial equation. After which, it's simply a question of which rational numbers $t$ yield natural $x$ and $y$ since $x$ and $y$ are guaranteed to be rational in this parameterization for any rational number $t$.

Comment: I tried concluding from there, but did not manage to find a nice form. Did you meanwhile conclude? Thanks!

Comment: Try this: If $x$ and $y$ are natural, then $4nt^2=y(4+3t^2)$ and $n(t+2)^2=x(4+3t^2)$. You can solve both of these equations for $t$ seperately. $t$ must be rational of course, so what are the conditions on $x$ and $y$ relative to $n$ relative to $t$ that guarantees $t$ is rational?

Comment: Also keep in mind that there is a symmetry $x\longleftrightarrow y$. So you can always search for an $n$ such that the parameterizations give at least $1011$ solutions.

Comment: I'd argue that "it's simply a question of which rational numbers $t$ yield natural $x$ and $y$" isn't that simple, and so you've not made much progress. IE How do you find (or show that there exists) a fixed $n$, so that there are (say) 10 values of $t$ such that $ 4nt^2 / ( 4+3t^2)$ is an integer?

Comment: @Calvin Lin There is some simplicity however. In the case $t=p/q$; $4nt^2/(4+3t^2) = 4np^2/(4q^2 + 3p^2)$. So $4q^2 + 3p^2 \vert 4,n,p $. Appealing only to $n$, this means $4q^2 + 3p^2$ is at minimum divisor of $n$. That give a divisor. So to find 10 integer solutions, there $n$ needs at least 10 divisors. For example, fixing $q$, you only need a number $n = \prod_{p=1}^{10} (4+3p^2)$. So the number $ n= \prod_{p=1}^{1011} (4+3p^2)$ would be an example of such a number with 2022 distinct pairs $(x,y)$ solving the equation.

Comment: Right, you just need to put that in the solution for it to be complete (or more accurately, for me to consider it complete).